# Wordpress users video gallery plugin

Tags: wordpress, video, plugins, gallery

Who knows if there is a wordpress plugin that allows people to add (YouTube and vimeo) video to the site?
Cost plugin does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automatically embed YouTube and Vimeo videos into posts and pages using the new oEmbed feature:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

Alternatively, you could try the rtMedia plugin:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-media/